# TestNG console output into log4j.log

Tags: java, automation, log4j, testng

I need to get output result (FAIL or SUCCESS) into log4j output.

```
Assert.assertTrue(availresponse);
```

Is there any way to add TestNG console output into log4j.log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the easiest way to log the `Assert error` in `log4j`

In `catch block` it should be `Throwable`, if it is `Exception` that will not work.

```
try {
    Assert.assertTrue(hotel.getAmenitiesList().size() < 0, "Hotel Amenities Available!");

} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("FAILED: testRoomAmenities ", e);
    Assert.fail();
```

When this implement that will not invoke as `FAIL`. It will show that scenario is `PASSED`. Therefore you should use `Assert.fail()` to make that is `FAILED`

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple, easy and perfect way to log TestNG output into log4j.log file. But this can't be log Final Report Details into log4j (PASS or FAIL).

```
implements ITestListener
```

Then add unimplemented methods

```
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    logger.info(result);
}

public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    logger.info(result);
}
```

You can add log4j logger in the methods you need. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you need that, you could use `if .. else` construct to do the logging.

```
if(null != availresponse) {
   //log success message
} else {
   //log failure message
}
```

Another way is to write a custom class implementing `TestListenerAdapter`. You can see full example code [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_custom_logger.htm).

Comment: Hi, I want to add output comes from Assert into log4j.

Comment: Add `log.info` or `log.error` statement accordingly in side the if construct. It should be logged.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the assert with a logger e.g.

```
log.info(Assert.assertNotNull(availresponse));
```

However this is a bit limited in terms of information.  What I usually do is:

```
    if(availresponse==null)
{
log.fatal("availresponse was null");
}

Assert.assertNotNull(availresponse);
```

I know it's a bit of a hassle, testing for the condition twice but it does allow you to tweak the output level of the logger and add any other information you think would be useful e.g. the variables which were used to determine the contents of availresponse.

Alternatively you could try getting the console output to appear in your log file in which case you'll need to add something like:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
```

to your log4j properties file.

Comment: Hi, I want to add output comes from Assert into log4j.

Comment: Asserts tend to be true or false, in which case the wrapper for the Assert of testing the condition seperately will tell you if the condition passed or failed.  You can add messages to them e.g. Assert.assertNotNull(availresponse, "Insert message here"); and you will see the message if the condition fails.  If you are talking about something else can you show me some code and the output from the console which you are refering to?  If you are refering to a null pointer message, that is probably coming from the JVM and not TestNG.

Comment: Yeah. Thats true. as you mention, I want to add that output from the console into log4j.log file as it is. I tried many times. but no way to find.

Comment: If I am going to be able to help you, you're going to have to post the contents of your log4j properties file, the logger variable declaration and an example of the output you want to logfile to contain.  If the suggestions above do not work (such as log.info(Assert()), there is not enough information to suggest anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `test-output` folder in your project PATH. `index.html` will show the Test output of Success or Fail.

- If the `testMethod()` is Success, there will no any output result shows in `index.html` file. You can add Success message by using `Reporter.log()`
- If `testmethod()` fail, automatically it will prints output in file.

  **NOTE** : `java.lang.AssertionError` is an error that thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed.

If anyone know how **TestNG** inserting that error to the report, comment below.