# How to log TestNG Report into log4j.log file

Tags: java, automation, log4j, testng

How to log TestNG Report into log4j.log file

Example :

```
===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 31, Failures: 9, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 31, Failures: 9, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

These final result and failed exceptions are need to logged in log4j.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `test-output` folder in your project PATH. `index.html` will show the Test output of **Success** or **Fail.**

> - Check with **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135505/testng-console-output-into-log4j-log)** answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ITestListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-gc0b72cf-169/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html) for that.

Check [this](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/) site which explains how to use the ITestListner.

In order to use log4j instead of testNG inbuild Reporter, you can replace `Reporter.log()` with log4j logger

Comment: Do you know how can I find the **PATH** of _Reporter.log()_ ?

Comment: What do you mean by PATH, can you explain little bit more?

Comment: I added Reporter.log(result). Is there any log file create by Reporter.log() or if not how we find that log?

Comment: Console is already there. but I need to log the TestNG output result as i show in question into log4j.log file. but still couldn't do that.

Comment: only java console can logged. i couldn't find any way to log TestNG output log details to the log4j.log file.

Comment: Since [org.testng.Reporter](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-gf77788e-171/javadoc/org/testng/Reporter.html) is inbuild logging for testng which is create an HTML file with test results.
If you really want to use log4j instead of Reporter, you can just replace `Reporter.log()` with log4j

Comment: [This](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/) tutorial will help you to configure log4j. Then you can simply use `logger.info()`.